# PI4 stuck when attaching USB HDD

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I was about to try using my PI4 as NAS and just plugged a WD drive to the USB 3.0. But that made the whole beast hang until I unplug the drive again. Running a `tail -f /var/log/messages` during attaching the drive shows

```
Feb 17 20:06:25 testpi mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 2: "/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2"
Feb 17 20:06:25 testpi mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 2 was not an MTP device
Feb 17 20:06:25 testpi mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 2: "/sys/devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb2/2-2"
Feb 17 20:06:25 testpi mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 2 was not an MTP device
Feb 17 20:06:26 testpi kernel: [  104.115808] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Elements 25A2    1014 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Feb 17 20:06:26 testpi kernel: [  104.119674] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
Feb 17 20:06:26 testpi kernel: [  104.139170] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Feb 17 20:06:31 testpi kernel: [  105.155055] .....ready
Feb 17 20:06:31 testpi kernel: [  109.315736] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 976707584 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
Feb 17 20:06:31 testpi kernel: [  109.316426] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Feb 17 20:06:31 testpi kernel: [  109.416900]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3
Feb 17 20:06:31 testpi kernel: [  109.420859] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

Any idea what I could do to get the HDD up and running?

P.S. dmesg as well:

```
[  103.015333] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  103.056629] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=25a2, bcdDevice=10.14
[  103.056649] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  103.056665] usb 2-2: Product: Elements 25A2
[  103.056681] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[  103.056696] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 575833314137363731413454
[  103.060623] usb-storage 2-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  103.064356] scsi host0: usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[  104.115808] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Elements 25A2    1014 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  104.119674] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[  104.139170] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[  105.155055] .....ready
[  109.315736] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 976707584 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[  109.316426] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[  109.316446] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
[  109.317136] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[  109.317154] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  109.416900]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda3
[  109.420859] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[  276.086679] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
```

Comment: looks like it loads fine

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, but it just hangs. Console input: nada. Until I unplug and the machine runs as if nothing happened :-/

Comment: no power messages in dmesg?

Comment: @JaromandaX Nope. I add the dmesg output as well. It's a tiny drive and the power supply is sufficient. The fact that it keeps running after unplugging says that power is not the issue.

Comment: As has been observed it loads properly these things are so picky with  the USB it could be anything. If I plug my keyboard it does not boot, plug it after that it works fine. My USB connected drive is in lay down connector, it works perfectly attached to the USB3 port as does the SSD used for /. The connector for my 6TB WD connected to my Pi 4 8GB is here if you wish to know confirmed working model. https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B01996V3VK/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: @HappyTux I would have suspected such kind of cause. Will try with different USBs lying around tomorrow and see what happens. Who knows, when i wake up I find a good answer too xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be one of the crude hardware issues. I plugged in another USB drive (having a Toshiba inside instead) and that worked with no issues. Don't spend time investigating such kind of strangeness if you can simply swap a piece of hardware.